# Rearranging parent-child activation order in Caliburn Micro

Tags: caliburn.micro

During my override of OnActivate() in my view-model, I need to call GetView() in order to focus an element.  When I do this after I have previously activated my view, it's fine.  But when I call this the first activation, it fails.

I was able to get it to work by swapping a few lines in ConductorBaseWithActiveItem.ChangeActiveItem.  The original is as follows:

```cs
protected virtual void ChangeActiveItem(T newItem, bool closePrevious) {
    ScreenExtensions.TryDeactivate(activeItem, closePrevious);
    newItem = EnsureItem(newItem);

    if(IsActive)
        ScreenExtensions.TryActivate(newItem);

    activeItem = newItem;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange("ActiveItem");
    OnActivationProcessed(activeItem, true);
}
```

and with my changes:

```cs
protected virtual void ChangeActiveItem(T newItem, bool closePrevious) {
    ScreenExtensions.TryDeactivate(activeItem, closePrevious);

    newItem = EnsureItem(newItem);

    activeItem = newItem;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange("ActiveItem");

    if (IsActive)
        ScreenExtensions.TryActivate(newItem);

    OnActivationProcessed(activeItem, true);
}
```

This seems to work.  Notifying that "ActiveItem" changed triggers the code to load and cache the view.  Then ScreenExtensions.TryActivate calls my OnActivate override.

Question:  I haven't noticed any problems doing this, but I'm curious if anyone knows better than I do what repercussions this change could have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is overriding Caliburn's `OnViewAttached` method and trying to focus it there. That being said, in MVVM, focus is more of a View concern, so if possible, that logic should be moved from the ViewModel to the View.

One way you may be able to solve this is by creating an attached behavior (you will need a reference to the `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` assembly):

```cs
public class FocusWhenVisibleBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += this.Loaded;
        this.AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged += this.VisibleChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= this.Loaded;
        this.AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged -= this.VisibleChanged;
    }

    private void Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TryFocus();
    }

    private void VisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TryFocus();
    }

    private void TryFocus()
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject.IsLoaded && this.AssociatedObject.IsVisible)
        {
            // Focus the control
            this.AssociatedObject.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

And that attaching that behavior to whatever control you want to focus:

```xml
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:FocusWhenVisibleBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Comment: Overriding `OnViewAttached` would work.  The behavior won't help my case though, because focus needs to be set dynamically based on matching the control name with information known only to the view-model.